# database structure / logic, im confused

Tags: database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I have two tables in SQL with a many-many relationship, do I need to create an additional table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125621/if-i-have-two-tables-in-sql-with-a-many-many-relationship-do-i-need-to-create-a)

I need some help on how to set this model up as data tables.

So, in my app I have "Items" and they have meta data like category, description, tags etc.

Say the item is a CD.

Now, any user can choose to *Relate* any two Items and an Item can have an infinite number of relations.

As well, each relation has a rating (say from 1 - 100) and a description.

How would i set this up in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different "entities" or ideas (as well as their metadata):

1. Item
2. Item relationship

Each item relationship has 2 items (FK relationships to items) and a rating.

The items (and their other metadata) I assume you understand, since you didn't focus on it.